# Problems with microphone

Tags: microphone

My Front mic doesn't seem to be working in ubuntu. I have even tried other mics but none of them work. I am relatively new to the OS. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After booting into Ubuntu open the terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Then run the `alsamixer` command.Press <kbd>F4</kbd> to go to the `Capture` tab.  From there set input source to `Front mic`. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit alsamixer. Then run `alsactl store` in terminal to save settings.